# File upload Web API is getting null client from Javascript client

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Chrome and trying to upload a file from browser client. My API given below.

```
[HttpPost("attachment/{confirmId:long}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAttachmentAsync(long confirmId, IFormFile filePayload)
{
     // ...
}
```

This works in `Swagger` but when I am trying from Javascript client, `filePayload` is `null`. The `confirmId` param comes through fine.

I used `HttpToolkit` and verified that the content of the file is there.

However, this is my client code anyway....

```
async uploadAttachmentAsync(file, confirmId) {

    // buildUrl is my own utility, creates url correctly
    const url = buildUrl(`paperConfirm/attachment/${confirmId}`); 

    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('file', file);

    // XH is a 3rd party library. I am confident there is no problem there
    return await XH.fetchJson({ 
        url,
        body,
        method: 'POST',
        // Note: We must explicitly *not* set Content-Type headers to allow the browser to set the boundary.
        // See https://stanko.github.io/uploading-files-using-fetch-multipart-form-data/ for further explanation.
        headers: {'Content-Type': null}
    });
}
```

Comment: For one, you have file and confirmId mixed, it should be async uploadAttachmentASync(confirmId, file), where are you setting filePayLoad i don't see it set.

Comment: Yes, indeed! I checked with `Request.Form.Files[0]` and saw the file is there so it had to be the non-matching parameter name. So after changing to `file` from `filePayload` I got the file.